# How to set "na.rm = TRUE " within R glue syntax

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am using `gtsummary::tbl_summary` to create a stats summary table.

```
stats_summary_table <-
  dat_wide%>%
  tbl_summary(by = mss_plate_id, 
              missing = "no",
              statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ " {mean} ± {sd}   {cv}"  ))
```

The `cv` function is from `goeveg` library. The report table shows cv value as 0. I suppose it is because of missing value in my data. So, my question is how to write `cv(x, na.rm = TRUE)` in the glue syntax.

Edit:
It turns out that the challenge is due to the precision issue but not setting `na.rm=TRUE`. So the solution is to set digits to 2 or 3 for cv. (see the marked answer and the comments with it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great question.

One of the difficult things `tbl_summary()` tries to do is guess how many digits to round statistics to. This example is tricky because you'll often want the mean and the CV to be shown at different levels of precision since they are not on the same scale. In the example below, `tbl_summary()` guessed that age should be shown rounded to the nearest integer. This is a reasonable assumption for the mean and SD, but we need to tell it to show more digits for CV. To do this, we use the `tbl_summary(digits=)` argument. There are three statistics being shown for age (mean, sd, and cv), and we'll pass a vector of length three, indicating how many digits to round each statistic to.

```r
library(goeveg)
library(gtsummary)

trial %>%
  select(age, marker) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ " {mean} ± {sd} [{cv}]"),
    digits = list(age ~ c(0, 0, 2))
  )
```

[image]

Hope this answers your question! Happy Coding!

Comment: Hi @Daniel Sjoberg thank you for responding to my questions promptly ... However, I am not sure it answers my question. My challenge is to compute cv with the same vector that gets mean and sd. Intuitively,  cv = sd * 100 / mean, but it is not clear to me how to implement that operation in glue. So I used `goeveg::cv`, but it only outputs 0, and I suppose it's because of missing value in the vector, so I like to set `na.rm = TRUE` for cv() in glue syntax.

Comment: In `tbl_summary()` all missing values are excluded before passing the vector to mean, sd, or cv, so you don't need to add `na.rm = TRUE`. Your CV is rounded to 0, but is not 0. The `goeveg::cv()` function is calculating CV without multiplying by 100. In the example above for age sd / mean = 14 / 47 = 0.30. `goeveg::cv(trial$age, na.rm = TRUE) = 0.30` as shown in the table.

Comment: That makes sense. It is because of digits but not na.rm. Turns out I asked the wrong question. Thank you.

Comment: It had me stumped when I first saw the question as well! Happy Programming!